# Android webview fail to load large html content (some part load as white)

Tags: android, memory, android-webview, rendering

I have a `WebView` load html data from a response in a `ViewPager` which contain `WebView`,so if I swipe fast the data will load but some portion will be white, initial i thought its a render issue `onRenderProcessGone` but it was not coming it to that method

```
@Override
    public boolean onRenderProcessGone(WebView view,
            RenderProcessGoneDetail detail) {
}
```

This is how the render webview in view pager looks like
[image]

if you see the above image you can see the some portion not rendered. if I swipe back  after going to other page, the data will load perfectly, so how can I solve the issue. i followed the [Managing `WebView` objects](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/managing-webview)
but noting is working, Hope some one will help to fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in chrome version v74, when we using webview inside cardview, as i can see your webview is inside cardview,So dont worry they have done a fix in canary version v75 for details check the link below
[Rendering issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=958810)

So for testing you can download the canary version of chrome from play-store and enable it as your webview from developer console, after that check whether you are getting the issue or not.
If fixed wait for the stable version of chrome v75 meanwhile if you need a urgent fix , i can suggest you that change the cardview to linear-layout and make card image with shadow as background,for generating card you can check [shadow4android](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)

Else wait for the stable relase,Hope this helped you

Comment: you are right Thank you, In canary version its working,also thank you for the idea but i think i will wait for the update? do you know when is the new update comming?

Comment: Just a rough schedule by chrome developers